# React-redux, reducer unable to update state,error in code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a simple counter code using React JS with hooks and redux where I can increment/decrement counter on button clicks. When compiling I get error *Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {count}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*

If I remove initialState and declare `state=0` it works fine, but how can I execute this code successfully be keeping initialState ?

```
let initialState ={
    count:0
}
const counter = (state=initialState,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'INCREMENT': return {...state,count:state.count+1} ;
        case 'DECREMENT':return {...state,count:state.count-1};
        default: return state
    }
}

export default counter
```

I consume the code in a component as mention below

```
    const counter = useSelector(state=>state.counter)
           <h3>{counter}</h3> 
# note : some code parts are removed from this component for reader easiness
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `state.counter` isn't a primitive value, it's an object that you keep in your store under `counter` field.

You can either go one level deeper:

```
const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter.count);
```

or directly refer to the `count` value inside JSX:

```
<h3>{counter.count}</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an object so you should distruct the count property like this:

```
const {count } = useSelector(state=>state.counter)
 <h3>{count}</h3>
```